# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:exec (npm run build) on project npm

Tags: node.js, maven, npm

I am trying to deploy my web-app to heroku. To run my app i need to execute

```
   npm run build
```

So i need to install npm to Heroku. I found maven plugins which does it.And a plugin which executes a script.

```
   <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- Use the latest released version:
            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/ -->
            <version>1.7.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                <!-- optional: you don't really need execution ids, but it looks nice in your build log. -->
                <id>install node and npm</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                </goals>
                <!-- optional: default phase is "generate-resources" -->
                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            </execution>

            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <nodeVersion>v11.15.0</nodeVersion>
                <npmDownloadRoot>https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.11.3/win-x64/node.exe</npmDownloadRoot>

            </configuration>

        </plugin>                     
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>npm run build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>npm</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>run</argument>
                            <argument>build</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But when i try to push it to heroku I get this:

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:exec (npm run build) on project vstup: Command execution failed. Cannot run program "npm" (in directory "/tmp/build_6883506630fbb2f73ce1bcb9a5d6cf3d"): error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0):

I had a same error today with GitLab-ci and the spring-boot app.

I had to run `before script` to install the missing `npm`:

```
before_script:
   - 'apt-get update'
   - 'apt-get install -y npm'
script:
   - 'mvn deploy'
```

This will install `npm` before running the maven exec plugin with the `npm` executable.

My `mvn` plugin configuration was:

```
           <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/frontend</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>exec-npm-install</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>npm</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>install</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
           </plugin>
```

Hint:

- maybe you can try to use `after_script` and `before_script` to run `ls -Ra` and see if a file or directory is missing, but it wasn't my case